# Get dynamically created Div child text

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic, click

I have one big problem. I have this code generated by PHP:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">Example text1</div>
 <a class="get_child_text">Get text</a>
</div>    

<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">Example text2</div>
 <a class="get_child_text">Get text</a>
</div>

<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">Example text3</div>
 <a class="get_child_text">Get text</a>
</div>
```

And I want to dynamically get text of "child" div which is in "parent" div where I've clicked a tag. Simply, I want to get "child" text by clicking in "get_child_text".
For example when I've clicked in third "get_child_text" I want to get (in 'alert' for example) "Example text3". I've tried with:`$('body').on('click', '.get_child_text', function() {(...)})` but it returns nothing. Help please!

**UPDATED**
Ok, thanks but if I have this situation (with few same "item" divs but with other text content:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="foto"><a rel="example_group" href="upload/foto04.jpg"><img id="miniatura" style="border:2px solid #fff;" src="upload/foto04.jpg"/></a><br><div id="details1" style="display:none;"><br><a style="margin-top:4px;" rel="example_group" href="upload/foto04.jpg">Powiększ zdjęcie</a><br><a href="#" class="kup" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Dodaj do koszyka</a></div></div>
    <div class="prawa_strona">
    <span id="id" style="display:none;">4</span>
    <div class="tytul" id="tytul">Przyk</div>
    <div id="opis1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet interdum ligula, eu rutrum purus. Nulla commodo justo et auctor sollicitudin. Nulla nibh lorem, mollis sit amet nisl sed, gravida fermentum mauris. Nullam dictum blandit interdum. Etiam pellentesque luctus elit, a semper nibh.</div>
    <div style="display:none;" id="opis_dlugi1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet interdum ligula, eu rutrum purus. Nulla commodo justo et auctor sollicitudin. Nulla nibh lorem, mollis sit amet nisl sed, gravida fermentum mauris. Nullam dictum blandit interdum. Etiam pellentesque luctus elit, a semper nibh. Aliquam vel purus tempus, porta magna ac, luctus erat. Integer ut dui metus. Aliquam blandit magna ac felis scelerisque fringilla quis nec eros. Fusce sit amet purus felis. Nunc posuere nisi eu mattis ullamcorper. </div>
    <div class="cena"><small>Cena: </small><b><span class="cena">2500</span> zł</b></div>
    <div class="more"><a href="#" class="wiecej_a1">Pokaż więcej...</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And I want to get ".cena" span text by clicking ".kup" a tag?

Comment: You must have unique IDs

Comment: Sure it returns nothig cause you use multiple `#` and `{(...)}` would never do nothing ;)

Comment: Assuming your second code block is relevant in some way, what do you want it to do? What should be clicked and what should it return? Also, why have you littered it with inline CSS? The point is to make it easier to debug and answer, while still representing your problem.

Comment: Next time please post all code from the beginning, so people don't loose time answering two times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest, at its simplest:

```
$('a.get_child_text').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var divText = $(this).prev('div').text();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kKqbS/1/) (adapted from that provided [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18707213/get-dynamically-created-div-child-text/18707239#comment27562935_18707239), purely because I prefer `console.log()` to `alert()`).

But do note that you have multiple elements sharing the same `id`, this is invalid HTML. Use a class instead.

If you wish to use the `on()` method instead, then I'd recommend:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.get_child_text', function(e){
    var divText = $(this).prev('div').text();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kKqbS/2/).

But, ideally, use a parent-element that's present on the page on document-ready, to prevent events having to bubble all the way to the `document`.

Given the updated question, the following HTML (having removed some of the in-line `style` attributes, *one* of which prevented the item to be clicked from being visible)):

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="foto"><a rel="example_group" href="upload/foto04.jpg"><img id="miniatura" style="border:2px solid #fff;" src="upload/foto04.jpg"/></a>

        <br />
        <div id="details1">
            <br /> <a style="margin-top:4px;" rel="example_group" href="upload/foto04.jpg">Powiększ zdjęcie</a>

            <br />
            <a href="#" class="kup">Dodaj do koszyka</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prawa_strona"> <span id="id" style="display:none;">4</span>

    <!-- stuff that doesn't matter, excised for brevity -->
        <div class="cena"><small>Cena: </small><b><span class="cena">2500</span> zł</b>

        </div>
        <div class="more"><a href="#" class="wiecej_a1">Pokaż więcej...</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd suggest using:

```
$('.kup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cenaText = $(this).closest('.item').find('.cena').text();
    console.log(cenaText);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bsLcQ/1/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [The global Structure of an HTML document: Element identifiers: the `id` and `class` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Comment: Joe: thanks! I've amended the demo you provided, before adding to the answer, because I prefer (as noted in the answer) to use `console.log()` rather than `alert()` for debugging (far less stopping/starting and clicking involved in the console) =)

Comment: @Sergio: but that works, so long as we're meant to click on the link that reads 'Dodaj do koszyka'?

Comment: See the updated answer. Also, if you want to click on something *don't* hide it in a `display: none` ancestor element.